# Sorting and separating data in UNIX shell

Tags: csv, unix

I am relatively new to using the unix shell, and i am having trouble with a .csv file. My aim is to create a new file that has all of the same data but sorted. I have achieved this to an extent where i use the command

```
sort -t, datafile.csv>newdatafile.csv
```

However i seem to lose some lines. The original file has 271116 lines and the new sorted file has 33889, why have some lines been thrown away?

I would also like to know how I can take the first 100 lines of a csv file and create a new file with just those 100 lines.

Thanks

Comment: How did you count the lines before and afterwards? Try `wc -l *.csv`

Answer (score 0):

To print the only the first 100 lines of a file you should use the command head:

`head -n 100 datafile.csv > newdatafile.csv`

By default head prints the first 10 lines.
Use -n xxx to print more or less lines.

Answer (score 0):

`awk` at the rescue:
Assuming it's a `.csv` file, then:

`awk -F"," 'NR == 1,NR == 100 {print $0 > "newdatafile.csv"}' datafile.csv`

It'll save the first 100 lines of the file into a new file named :newdatafile.csv

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You are very close w.r.t the sorting requirement of your question:

use the below command, for example, to sort based on column 3 in your csv:

sort -t, -k3 datafile.csv>newdatafile.csv

This will sort the file based on column 3 alphabetically.

In case of numerical columns, use the below command to sort ascending:

sort -t, -nk3 datafile.csv>newdatafile.csv

To sort descending numerically:

sort -t, -nrk3 datafile.csv>newdatafile.csv

Also to get the first 100 rows from the sorted file use :

sort -t, -k3 datafile.csv | head -100 >newdatafile.csv

This will sort the datafile.csv alphabetically on column 3 and then select first 100 rows and write into newdatafile.csv